# Complicated Query in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I was wondering if you guys could help with a complicated query.
I have three tables of note.

Users, Jobs and Comments.

Jobs are assigned to users, but any user can leave a comment on a job.
At the moment, after baking the traditional way, the `View Job` view shows related comments at the bottom. However, the Comments table shows a numeric `user_id` whereas I want it to display the 'username' that is matched with said `user_id`.

In the `View Job` view, I have this array, with their respective keys:

```
$job;
$job['Users'];
$job['Comments'];
$job['Job'];
```

And here is my debug output of the `$job` Array.

```
Array
(
    [Job] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [user_id] => 1
            [title] => New Job
            [body] => adsljbfalwsjbflkjb
            [deadline] => 2011-07-15
            [completed] => 0
        )

    [User] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [username] => dan
            [password] => 2fd27a6319ef3faf9ed55b59830d786b5ed890be
        )

    [Comment] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [job_id] => 1
                    [user_id] => 2
                    [hours] => 6
                    [body] => Comment from Phil
                    [date] => 2011-07-12
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [job_id] => 1
                    [user_id] => 1
                    [hours] => 2
                    [body] => This is a Comment from the 9th
                    [date] => 2011-07-09
                )

        )

)
```

Could I do something with these that would allow me to display the username and not the user_id? Do I modify the Model? The Controller?
I'm rather new to CakePHP and although I've grasped the basics, I'm struggling with the more complicated queries like this.

Here is my view file that I want to change:

```
<div class="related">
    <h3><?php __('Comments'); ?></h3>
    <?php if (!empty($job['Comment'])): ?>
        <table cellpadding = "0" cellspacing = "0">
            <tr>
                <th><?php __('User'); ?></th>
                <th><?php __('Date'); ?></th>
                <th><?php __('Hours'); ?></th>
                <th><?php __('Body'); ?></th>
                <th class="actions"><?php __('Actions'); ?></th>
            </tr>
            <?php
            $i = 0;
            foreach ($job['Comment'] as $comment):
                $class = null;
                if ($i++ % 2 == 0) {
                    $class = ' class="altrow"';
                }
                ?>
                <tr<?php echo $class; ?>>
                    <td><?php echo $comment['user_id']; ?></td> // NEEDS TO BE USERNAME NOT USER ID
                    <td><?php echo $comment['date']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $comment['hours']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $comment['body']; ?></td>                   
                    <td class="actions">
                        <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('View', true), array('controller' => 'comments', 'action' => 'view', $comment['id'])); ?>
                        <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Edit', true), array('controller' => 'comments', 'action' => 'edit', $comment['id'])); ?>
                        <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Delete', true), array('controller' => 'comments', 'action' => 'delete', $comment['id']), null, sprintf(__('Are you sure you want to delete # %s?', true), $comment['id'])); ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>+
        </table>
    <?php endif; ?>

</div>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: In your view, `debug($job)` and post what you have. I'm betting it's already in there.

Comment: @Jason McCreary I've updated the question with the output.

Comment: Would need to see some controller/model code, but yes this is possible. Are you modifying `$this->Model->recursive` at all? That can effect how deep the associations go without any additional work.

Comment: You have to set the $displayField on the Model. See answer below...

Comment: `$this->Model->recursive` should not work for you due to the fact that you are looking for a model's children's other parent.

Comment: can you show the part of the view file you want to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the same issue by running a find('list') on the model you would like to retrieve the names from.

In your case you would like to find Users->find('list') and assign it to a variable in your controller and then in your view where the id displays you add that new variable over the id.

e.g. change $job['Comment']['user_id'] to $users[$job['Comment']['user_id']]

Comment: You however have to run the find on a model within a controller that does not have that model loaded. If you find a good way to load that model please comment how you did it.

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you. Controller: `$this->set('users', $this->Job->User->find('list'));` Then in my View: `$users[$job['Comment']['user_id']];`

Comment: I wouldn't opt for this solution, because another query is run additionally to what Cake does in order to fetch associations. Therefore the resulting database load is unnecessary. The `$displayField` is a more 'Caky' solution, as stated in the other reply, and my comments will (hopefully) clarify all your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to set de `displayField` attribute on your `User` Model.

```
class User extends AppModel { var $displayField = 'username';}
```

Comment: If this is the case, bear in mind that you'll have to rebake your views so that this change takes effect.

Comment: @Beto Frega: How do you rebake views without rebaking the controller (which effectively removes what you suggested to add)?

Comment: @linkyndy I've made a considerable amount of change to the view itself, so I'd not wish to re-bake. What change to the code would this make? I can make any code changes manually not to upset my other modifications.

Comment: It is not necessary. Rebaking would have been useful if you hadn't modified the generated views. In this case, replace all `$comment['user_id']` with `$comment['User']['username']`. Also, don't forget to set `$this->Jobs->recursive = 2` in the controller to be sure that the associated user is fetched together with the comment. In general, the `$displayField` property from the model sets the visible field associated to that model in the views. If the property is missing, the default field is used (`id`).

Comment: @linkyndy: Strange statement you make there, since in my app I used name instead of username, and this caused my other views to display the correct name (due to convention over configuration) except for the view.ctp's related models which does not retrieve the required information even with recursive 2. You sure about this?

Comment: I was talking about related models, because this was the case the OP asked about. So, when you call the `find('all')` method, all related models are fetched, depending on the level of recursion, `$this->Model->recursive`. You need to select the level of recursion in order to fetch the desired level of model association. And regarding the other aspect, when views are baked, the display field of the associated model is used to display the associated records. Therefore, if you change the display field afterwards, you need to change also what Cake has baked for you (e.g.: the field name).

Comment: And the reason why it worked for you with the `name` field is that it is the default field which is displayed by Cake, if you don't specify another (and also if the defaults exists in the database's schema). The default are `name` and `title`. More info here: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1062/displayField